# Can't expose Flink metrics to Prometheus

Tags: java, apache-flink, prometheus, jmx

I'm trying to expose the built-in metrics of Flink to Prometheus, but somehow Prometheus doesn't recognize the targets - both the [JMX](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#jmx-orgapacheflinkmetricsjmxjmxreporter) as well as the [PrometheusReporter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#prometheus-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheusreporter).

The scraping defined in `prometheus.yml` looks like this:

```yml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: node
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']

  - job_name: 'kafka-server'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:7071']

  - job_name: 'flink-jmx'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8789']

  - job_name: 'flink-prom'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9249']
```

And my `flink-conf.yml` has the following lines:

```yml
#metrics.reporters: jmx, prom
metrics.reporters: jmx, prometheus

#metrics.reporter.jmx.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporterFactory
metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 8789

metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9249
```

However, both Flink targets are down when running a [WordCount](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java)

- in IntelliJ
- as jar: `java -jar target/flink-word-count.jar --input src/main/resources/loremipsum.txt`
- as Flink job: `flink run target/flink-word-count.jar --input src/main/resources/loremipsum.txt`

According to the Flink docs I don't need any additional dependencies for JMX and a copy of the provided `flink-metrics-prometheus-1.10.0.jar` in `flink/lib/` for the Prometheus reporter.

What am I doing wrong? What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

That particular job is going to run to completion pretty quickly, I believe. Once you get the setup working there may be no interesting metrics because the job doesn't run long enough for anything to show up.

When you run with a mini-cluster (as `java -jar ...`), the `flink-conf.yaml` file isn't loaded (unless you've done something rather special in your job to get it loaded). Note also that this file is normally has a `.yaml` extension; I'm not sure if it works if `.yml` is used instead.

You can check the jog manager and task manager logs to make sure that the reporters are being loaded.

FWIW, the last time I did this I used this setup, so that I could scrape from multiple processes:

```yml
# flink-conf.yaml

metrics.reporters: prom
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9260
```

```yml
# prometheus.yml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'flink'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9250', 'localhost:9251']
```

Comment: The job runtime is about 23 seconds because I actually use five large files and set the parallelism to 1. Besides that, I should be able to see metrics when navigating to `http://localhost:9249/metrics` when the job is running, which is not the case.

The job manger configuration also displays the reporters and ports as I set them in the flink-conf. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything suspicious in the logs.

Comment: I recommend you switch to debugging this with a continuous streaming job.